# How to add characters to originally data?

Tags: r, http

How to add characters to originally data

My data is organized as follows.

RED1

RED2

RED3

YELLO

I want to add characters to the data here.

For example, adding all http:// color.com

http:// color.com RED1

http:// color.com RED2

http:// color.com RED3

http:// color.com RED4

*Originally, there should be no spacing left behind at http://

(Link to link was performed by link.)

When you want to do this
What function should I do?

Comment: You can use `paste0` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 test <- c("Red", "Red1")
 paste0("http://", test, sep = "")
 # [1] "http://Red"  "http://Red1"
```

Comment: My original data is <a href="/qna/detail.nhn?d1id=7&amp;dirId=70111&amp;docId=280471008" rel="KIN">

When I use post0, I get attached to it.
http://kin.naver.com<a href=\"/qna/detail.nhn?d1id=7&amp;dirId=70111&amp;docId=280470501\" rel=\"KIN\">

Is there any way to put it in front of "/qna/detail.nhn" ??

Comment: That is a different question from the posted one.

Comment: you could use the `gsub()` but I suspect you really need to look at the `htmltools` package